# Ruby csv - delete row if column is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Trying to delete rows from the csv file here with Ruby without success.

How can I tell that all rows, where column "newprice" is empty, should be deleted?

```
require 'csv' 
guests = CSV.table('new.csv', headers:true)

guests.each do |guest_row|
  p guests.to_s 
end

price = CSV.foreach('new.csv', headers:true) do |row|
  puts row['newprice'] 
end 

guests.delete_if('newprice' = '')

File.open('new_output.csv', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(guests.to_csv)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. The `table` method changes the headers to symbols, and `delete_if` takes a block, the same way as `each` and `open`.

```
require 'csv' 
guests = CSV.table('test.csv', headers:true)

guests.each do |guest_row|
  p guest_row.to_s 
end

guests.delete_if do |row| 
  row[:newprice].nil?
end

File.open('test1.csv', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(guests.to_csv)
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, I used the other block form and forgot about it. Corrected.